# Git replaced all of my LF with CRLF - How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, newline

I just ran a

```
git add -A
```

on my first git project.

I got back about a thousand responses:

> "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF"

as it went through each file (Ruby files, some are gems).

I deleted my .git directory and tried to disable this default setting by typing this command:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Then I tried to add the files again:

```
git add -A
```

But I got the same result. Help!

Comment: What OS/platform are you using?

Comment: postimum related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332349/best-practices-for-cross-platform-git-config

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You likely have the `core.autocrlf` attribute set to true

It's a configuration attribute you can set:

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_out_and_checking_in

To make sure that is set to false for all Git projects you can do:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: To qualify the last recommendation above, if the core.autocrlf flag is set in a particular project, it will shadow the global setting. Hence, it's still necessary to either set or remove the flag from a project that has it defined locally.